# Как получить Улицу, Дом, Город с помощью SearchManager по координатам

Tags: android, yandexmapkit

```
public void onSearchResponse(Response response) {    
    GeoObjectCollection data = response.getCollection();
    String street = data.getChildren().get(0).getObj().getName();
    String city =  data.getChildren().get(4).getObj().getDescriptionText()
}
```

Так получаю улицу и название города по координатам

Проблема заключается в том что не всегда 4 элемент коллекции содержит название города, может содержать и городской округ. Каким образом получить адрес типа *Василькова, 46, Иваново*

Comment: К сожалению, очень мало информации о вашей проблеме. Какое api вы используете? В каком виде приходит json ?

Comment: Использую библиотеку от Yandex для Android Yandex MapKit

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста, полность ответ который возвращается в формате json

Comment: Я не знаю содержимое возвращаемого json, я использую готовый клиент от yandex который сам берет на себя отправку запроса получение  ответа и десериализацию, а работаю с готовыми объектами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема понятная и общеизвестна. Заключается она в том, что геокодер, каким бы он хорошим не был (В вашем случае -- это yandex геокодер) ошибается. Это происходит и должно происходить по нескольким причинам.

Одним из возможных решений, которое можно предложить для того, чтобы частично пофиксить проблему, является [*Libpostal*](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal). Эта утилита умеет парсить адрес. Но Вы можете найти соответствующие примеры, в т.ч. на java и использовать его на андроиде. Если по каким-то причинам это невозможно сделать, то всегда можно поднять сервер, который будет работать на удалённой машине. Этот сервер будет общаться с Вашим приложением через [RestAPI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) или, например, [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) (как вариант [gRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRPC)). Это сервер будет принимать на вход строку и отдавать ответ, который генерирует *Libpostal*.

Пример работы:

Запрос:

```
Franklin Ave Crown Heights Brooklyn NYC NY 11216 USA
```

Ответ:

```
{
    'house_number': '781',
    'road': 'franklin ave',
    'suburb': 'crown heights',
    'city_district': 'brooklyn',
    'city': 'nyc',
    'state': 'ny',
    'postcode': '11216',
    'country': 'usa'
}
```

Работает, в т.ч. и для русского языка.

В вашем случае, я предлагаю для каждого поля, полученного от яндекса ответа, пропускать через *Libpostal* и делать соответствующие правки.